# Expo-Image-Picker does not work on android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I use Expo SDK47(the latest). I can choose a photo but it returns me an object with undefined properties (I added the result below). It works on ios but not Android devices ( Samsung and Huawei).
My code is like that. I followed the documentation.

```
    async function handleImage(){        
            try {
                let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
                    quality: 1,
                  });
              
                  if (!result.cancelled) {
                    setImage(result.uri);
                  }
                  console.log(result) 
           } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
           }
    }
```

```
Object {
  "assetId": undefined,
  "base64": undefined,
  "cancelled": undefined,
  "exif": undefined,
  "height": undefined,
  "type": undefined,
  "uri": undefined,
  "width": undefined,
}
```

I tried to choose different libaries but it doesnt change. I tried to downgrade my packages. I doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem and I downgrade the version to 13.3.1 then it worked. No config needed for expo(not sure about CLI).

Comment: what did you downgrade the imagepicker version?

Answer (score 0):

For image using Expo SDK, please refer to more details here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/.

For Huawei environment, if you want to try Huawei SDK, you can try ML SDK:

Java: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/image-classification-0000001050040095

React Native: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/image-classification-0000001051086164-V1

Function to choose image for object detection.

```
ImagePicker() { ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else {

    this.setState({
      imageUri: response.uri,
    });

    this.startAnalyze();
  }
});
}
```